# Chef recipe for mysql secure installation

Tags: mysql, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I am looking for help regarding secure installation of mysql using chef. I am pretty much new to chef and I am unable to figure out few things. I would like to know how mysql secure installation can be done.

After installing and starting the mysql daemon which is pretty straightforward, I need to secure mysql

I see my road blocks here

How do I change the temporary password of root user in mysql. The following linux command gives me the initial temporary password.

```
cat /var/log/mysqld.log |grep "temporary password"|awk '{print $NF}'
```

How to I change this to my desired password?

Answer (score -1):

The answer to any "How do I do X with Chef?" is to work out how you would do it without Chef, and then put that in a recipe. "Secure installation of mysql" means many things to many people, so you'll have to work out exactly what that means for you.